# Creating a MVC Model Class in php properly

Tags: php, class, model-view-controller, web-applications

I'm having a go at creating my own php mvc website.

I have created the view, model, and controller but i am having trouble using my classes and objects properly...

I have a model class that has a function to create a connection to the DB and return some data into an array. This function is accessed by the controller when index.php is accessed. I then pump the data out into a html table with pagination.

If i click on the next page in my pagination it then goes and grabs the same array from the model.. however because the function is recreating all the sql again seem very redundant.. i know this probably a basic oo prgamming question but how to i create my model class so that i can reuse the array without having to create it from scratch everytime i want to grab the next chunk of data...

Here is an outline of my model class, i have removed all code relating the db commands and creating the array for simplicity. How do i structure the class so that i create the array once and then reuse it across my application when required. thanks in advance.

```
<?php
class Pagination_m extends CI_Model {

        public $myarray = array();

        public function get_data()
        {


                //sql connection implemented

                //Sql query executed

                //create an array

                //return the array to index.php
                return $myarray;

        }

        public function get_array()
        {
                //all other pages clicked will just return the created array rather than doing all the database work again..

                return $myarray;
        }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the structure of pagination.

I think you could doing the method 'get_data' receive an argument to control what page you are, and this argument will change the LIMIT of your SQL. Receive that information from your HTML and send for your model. Prepare your 'get_data' for every call without the page number parameter get the first page of your query.

Comment: Thanks Rafael for your response however im not too worried about how i am implementing pagination at this stage but more about sharing the array across multiple areas of the application without going back to the database. thanks.

Comment: So, I suppose you want use the same loaded data in multiples HTTP requests. It's not possible because php doesn't have an Application Context like Java, for example. To solve this problem you need to create a cache file and every time the http request was executed, your application get that data again into the array. Or if you want to share that data in lifetime of once http request, you might transform your array in a static variable or pass the responsibity to carry the data for your controller because it will be a mediator between UI and your model.